# I want to hide all element with <a> tag and contain a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Please I want to hide `<a>` that contains a link **sabdel.com** .

I used the below javascript code but it doesn't work

```js
window.addEventListener=()=>{
  var elem=document.querySelectorAll("a");
  var i;
  for(i=0;i<elem.length;i++){
    var obj=elem[i];
    if(obj.innerHTML.toString().includes('sabdel.com')){
        obj.style.display="none";
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <img src="//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Haabbc1065ea449668ced4bf88021f4aea.png">
        <p></p>
        <div style="margin-left:36.847599164927%;margin-top:-30.27139874739%;width:19.72860125261%">
          <a href="//www.sabdel.com/item/detail/4000105891117.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
            <img src="//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/He3f2750635b24a4d9e30666180dfacc89.png">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left:57.306889352818%;margin-top:-29.958246346555%;width:19.72860125261%">
          <a href="//www.sabdel.com/item/detail/4000147845779.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
            <img src="//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/He3f2750635b24a4d9e30666180dfacc89.png">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left:77.76617954071%;margin-top:-29.958246346555%;width:19.72860125261%">
          <a href="//www.sabdel.com/item/detail/4000990281325.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
            <img src="//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/He3f2750635b24a4d9e30666180dfacc89.png">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top:0.31315240083507%;height:0;width:0"></div>
      </div>
    <div>
      <img src="//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H69979517a8a248e9a84aec8986854e277.png">
      <p></p>
      <div style="margin-left:1.5657620041754%;margin-top:-31.524008350731%;width:22.964509394572%">
        <a href="//www.sabdel.com/item/detail/4000985761425.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
          <img src="//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H6dac222274304fc4afe554f53ea88bcds.png">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:26.096033402923%;margin-top:-30.793319415449%;width:22.964509394572%">
        <a href="//www.sabdel.com/item/detail/4000224026872.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
          <img src="//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H6dac222274304fc4afe554f53ea88bcds.png">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:50.62630480167%;margin-top:-30.793319415449%;width:22.964509394572%">
        <a href="//www.sabdel.com/item/detail/1005001597400364.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
          <img src="//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H6dac222274304fc4afe554f53ea88bcds.png">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:75.156576200418%;margin-top:-30.793319415449%;width:22.964509394572%">
        <a href="//www.sabdel.com/item/detail/4001044974112.html" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
          <img src="//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/H6dac222274304fc4afe554f53ea88bcds.png">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:0.73068893528184%;height:0;width:0"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What output generates your code?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are incorrectly using `addEventListener`. Second, you must check the `href` attribute, not `innerHTML`:

```
window.addEventListener("yourEvent", () => {
  var elem=document.querySelectorAll("a");
  for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    if(elem[i].href.includes('sabdel.com')) {
      elem[i].style.display="none";
    }
  }
}
```

Replace `yourEvent` with the event you want to listen with. For example, if you are listening for a click event, replace it with `click`.

Comment: thank you sir for your replay I tried your code in jsfidel but I get an error

Comment: @sabdelsabdel When you get an error it helps knowing what error you're getting.

Comment: I try it in jsfidel it seems not working in my case
https://jsfiddle.net/sabdel2016/uxcfsdzk/41/

Comment: @sabdelsabdel you have to replace `yourEvent` with the event you want to listen to.

Comment: sorry I am new in java script what I need to do in event

Comment: For a example, if you are listening to a click event on your button, replace `window` with your button and `yourEvent` with `click`.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean like this ?

```
window.addEventListener = () => {
  var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    var attributeValue = tags[i].getAttribute('href');

    if (attributeValue.includes('sabdel.com')) {
      tags[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank,you sir I try it but it doesn' worked
https://jsfiddle.net/sabdel2016/uxcfsdzk/46/
thanks for your help

Comment: yes, because you write window.addEventListenerr, not window.addEventListener. There is double r